# Does birchat hachodesh need three people?

Tags: tefilla, beit-din-court, rosh-chodesh-new-month, maseches-rosh-hashana

Does birchat hachodesh need three (or four) people preferably as a commemoration to Beth Din?

Comment: Check this out https://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/pdf_digest/Chelek_4/1134_Siman_417_Seif_1.pdf

Comment: Does it need anything? Does it even need to be said? All of it is seemingly a custom. Do whatever is customary in your location.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Moshe for the reference which says in part

> Mishnah Berurah then notes that blessing the month is not similar to
>   the sanctification of the new month that would be done during the time
>   of Sanhedrin. Rather, the reason we bless the new month is so that
>   people should know which day is Rosh Chodesh so that they will be
>   prepared to observe its halachos

which makes it clear that the ceremony is not a commemoration  of the sanctification of the new month and so does not need 3 or 4 people.